# Salat according to the Prophet

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad

I have a question regarding salat. Where should I keep my eyes during bowing, between 2 prostration and tashahud. According to Quran and ahadiths. Please mention the references. As I want to follow the Prophet's prayer not according to madhabs.

Comment: Related question [Where should we look during Salah?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/where-should-we-look-during-salah)

Answer (score 1):

The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: The people who lift their eyes towards the sky in Prayer should avoid it or they would lose their eyesight.

The Messenger forbade looking at the sky in bowing, rather you should keep your head level.

It was narrated that the Messenger entered the Ka'ba, and his eyesight did not leave the place where his forehead would touch the ground for prostration until he left.

So always look to where your forehead will touch the ground.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: It's the best explanation. I always keep my eyes on the ground where my forehead touch. Wether it's on tashahud, bowing or between two prostration.Many thnx.