# Is this method of raising index finger in tashahhud correct?

Tags: salat, fiqh, sunnah, muslim-practices, tashahhud

With my right hand, I create a ring with my thumb and middle finger and raise the index finger from the very start of the tashahhud and drop it just before the tasleem. It is kept pointing towards the Qibla at 90 degrees to the ground without moving it and my eyes are fixed to it as opposed to the place of sujood.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help] for more information about our site and model, Related posts: [Where should we look during salah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17837/where-should-we-look-during-salah). and [Why do people pray differently](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37458/why-do-people-pray-salah-differently). What is/are the source/s for your described tashahhud?